# Create a transparent arrow

Tags: html, css, svg

I need to create a transparent arrow as shown in the below script.

```css
.container{
  height:250px;
  background-image:url('https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/11/22/05/background-1134468_960_720.jpg');
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.container:after{
  content:'';
  clear:both;
  display:block;
}
.left,
.right{
  width:50%;
  float:left;
  height:100%;
}
.right{
  background-color:#555;
}
.arrow1{
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 125px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid #555;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
.arrow2{
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 125px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid #555;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  top: -50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="arrow1"></div>
  <div class="arrow2"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

I kind of got what I want, but the problem is that I don't know the height of `<div class="container">` which is set on `250px` here for testing purposes. the border of the `.arrow1` always has to be half of the height of `.container`. But since I can't use percent-values here I do not know how to perceed.
I think the best way would be having a svg with the shape, but I do not have any vector programms and the online solutions I found won't work properly. Does anyone have an alternative way?

Comment: Are you ready to use JS or not ?

Comment: JS/JQuery is no problem. I have already tried getting `$('.container').css('height');` or `$('.container').height();` and applying half of the height to the border. But apparently I dont get the proper height of the element. It's always between 200 and 300px smaller than it actually is.

Answer (score 0):

I did notice that none of the classes have opacity.  Generally when I am working with CSS and need something to be transparent in some way, I use opacity and it works out quite well.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

```
.right{
  background-color:#555;
  opacity: .5;  
}
.arrow1{
  opacity: .5;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 125px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid #555;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
.arrow2{
  opacity: .5;  
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 125px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid #555;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  top: -50%;
}
```

I did take a look at things on this codepen, should help.

http://codepen.io/KDweber89/pen/RRObbm?editors=1100#0

Comment: I think you kind of missunderstood my request. I do not want to get the white part transparent. My problem is that the transparent arrow (the thing that gets formed by `.arrow1` and `.arrow2` ) is static. I need it to be in percentage of the rest of the element. So that it is responsive.